# My project give this error on server but work fine in local System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

My software give this error on server

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

It work fine on local, I used jquery for date time. My date format is dd-mm-yyyy it work fine last night but morning it giving me this error.

```
protected void btnapprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnapprove.Text == "Approve")
        if (txtremark.Text != "")
        {
            fillSaveapprove();
            SaveProposalregis["IsActive"] = "Approve";
            string str = lo.SaveProposalregis(SaveProposalregis);


            if (str == "Save")
            {
                cleartext();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Approve Successfull')", true);
                GridViewregis.DataBind();
                panelgridview.Visible = true;
                GridViewregis.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Status Not Update SuccessFully')", true);
                panelgridview.Visible = false;
                panelshow.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please Fill Remark')", true);
            panelgridview.Visible = true;
            panelshow.Visible = true;
        }
}
public void fillSaveapprove()
{
    SaveProposalregis["id"] = Convert.ToInt64(hid.Value);
    SaveProposalregis["plvcid"] = Convert.ToInt64(plvcid.Value);
    SaveProposalregis["bankname"] = lblbankname.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Address"] = lbladd.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["First_Name"] = lblfirstname.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Last_Name"] = lblln.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Father_Name"] = lblfn.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["DOB"] = lbldob.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Contact_No"] = lblconno.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Email_Id"] = lblemail.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Pan_Detail"] = lblpanno.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Nominee_Name"] = lblnomineename.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Gender"] = lblngender.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["nominee_dob"] = lblndob.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["nominiRelationwithroposer"] = lblnrwp.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["l_a_Name"] = lbllaname.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["l_a_gender"] = lbllagender.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["l_a_dob"] = lblladob.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["l_a_Relationwithroposer"] = lbllarew.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Application_No"] = lblappno.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Plan"] = lblplan.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Company_name"] = lblcompname.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Primium_paying_Term"] = lblppt.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Policy_Term"] = lblpt.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Mode_of_Payment"] = lblmop.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Cheque_No"] = lblcn.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Cheque_Amount"] = lblcamount.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Cheque_Date"] = lblchqdate.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Demand_Draft_No"] = lblddno.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["DD_Payee_Name"] = lblddpayeename.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["DD_amount"] = lblddamount.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["dd_Date"] = lbldddate.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Primium_mode"] = lblprimiummode.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Employeee_code"] = lblempcode.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Manager"] = lblmanager.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Tl_name"] = lbltlname.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["tc_name"] = lbltcname.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["GrossPrimium"] = lblgrossprimium.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["NetPrimium"] = lblnetprimium.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["ModelPrimium"] = lblmodelprimium.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["RegistrationDate"] = lbldate.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["country"] = lblcountry.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["state"] = lblstate.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["city"] = lblcity.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["pinno"] = lblpinno.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["alternateno"] = lblalternateconno.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["Remark"] = txtremark.Text;
    SaveProposalregis["PlvcStatus"] = "Approve";


}`
```

Comment: I don't see any `DateTime` parsing in your code. Can you please show the relevant code only? What cultures your local and your server uses?

Comment: Sounds like a culture problem.

Comment: `SaveProposalregis["RegistrationDate"] = lbldate.Text;` - You need to check `lbldate.Text` is a valid string.. and `lbldob`, `lblladob`, `lblndob`, `lblchqdate`....

Comment: This happens when you treat dates as strings. You need to convert the strings stored in the textbox to datetime using an appropriate converter (Probably DateTime.TryParseExact) Millions of examples on this site, just search for CONVERT STRING TO DATETIME

Comment: i am saving my date time as a nvarchar in table then why it give me this kind of error in my table i set dob as nvarchar then why it give me this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by your local machine and server having having different cultures (due to having different region settings).

For example, if your local machine has UK regional settings and so has DD/MM/YYYY date format but your server has US regional settings and so has a MM/DD/YYYY.

For example, If the date represented by the 25th December 2015 was converted to a string on a UK machine it would produce "25/12/2015", however if you then parse that date on a US machine then you will get an error because there is no 25th month.

If you want to work with dates as strings then you need to make allowance for different date formats.

Comment: how can i change date format actully i fetch data from other table please send me convert date code in this way dd-mm-yyyy